# ERROR: invalid namespace puppeteer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, puppeteer

i made a simple program that gets the users fortnite level and current xp, but included is an unknown error (ERROR: invalid namespace) i have checked my code and i cannot find the problem this is my code:

```
let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/Twitch.BadGuyBen');
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let stats = document.querySelector('.top-stats').innerText;

        return {
            stats
        }

    });

    browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    let str = value.stats;
    let arr = str.split("\n");

    var lvl = "Level: " + arr[0];
    var xp = "Total XP: " + arr[4];

    console.log(lvl);
    console.log(xp);
});
```

i have tried to reinstall my node_modules folder i have updated my node to 9.9.0 but i still get the same error

EDIT: 
for @artur
the only error i get is:

[ERROR:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vezpz.png)

EDIT: after reinstalling puppeteer and also changing parts of my code as suggested by @Artur P. i still get the ERROR: invalid namespace, i will also try to further investigate this error

Comment: Put full error log please

Comment: @Artur i added the only error i get when launching the index.js "node index.js"

Comment: I think this error message come from puppeteer or chrominium instance

Comment: Try run cmd with admin rights

Comment: @Artur nope still getting the same error even with admin rights

Comment: Or i have better, faster, lightweight solution than using puppeteer. 
Your player data is currently in plain html file, we need simple `request` npm module, i can help you do this :)
`<script type="text/javascript">var accountInfo = {"AccountId":"f0a77f97-ac77-41b6-8c1f-6c12cd528d49","Nickname":"Twitch.BadGuyBen","Platform":3,"PlatformDisplayName":null,...`

Comment: thanks but i already have all that info from the provided api its just the player level and current XP is not included

Answer (score 0):

Callback in `page.evaluate()` function is inherently evaluating in brower ecosystem (like in chrome console). So when you try assing new variable `let stats` that can cause ERROR: invalid namespace i think.
You can try change a little bit this function:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
        stats: document.querySelector('.top-stats').innerText
    };
});
```

But in my environment (Windows 10, NodeJS 9.8.0) both versions are valid and not output any error code. I cant find any other resource about this error in  web.
Try uinstall puppeteer and install again with admin rights.

```
npm uninstall --save puppeteer
npm i --save puppeteer
```

What is your operating system?

Comment: i am on windows 10 64bit i will try this in the morning as it is 00:35 for me (note: i have tried to install puppeteer again and again even making new folders, my friend copied my code and ran it and had no error only the results) node version 9.9.0 now that i updated

Comment: EDIT: i have tried with your suggestion and i still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

My second solution (little offtopic), but is the best solution :)

```
npm i request request-promise


'use strict';
const request = require('request-promise');

const reg = /<script type="text\/javascript">var LifeTimeStats = ([^<]*);<\/script>/g;

(async () => {
  const response = await request('https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/Twitch.BadGuyBen');
  const LifeTimeStats = JSON.parse(reg.exec(response)[1]);
  console.log(LifeTimeStats); // all stats here :)
})();
```

You can add try catch and some one features what you want.

this is output:

```
[ { Key: 'Top 3', Value: '47' },
  { Key: 'Top 5s', Value: '81' },
  { Key: 'Top 3s', Value: '126' },
  { Key: 'Top 6s', Value: '217' },
  { Key: 'Top 12s', Value: '165' },
  { Key: 'Top 25s', Value: '92' },
  { Key: 'Score', Value: '325,855' },
  { Key: 'Matches Played', Value: '1523' },
  { Key: 'Wins', Value: '99' },
  { Key: 'Win%', Value: '7%' },
  { Key: 'Kills', Value: '3975' },
  { Key: 'K/d', Value: '2.79' },
  { Key: 'Kills Per Min', Value: '0.5' },
  { Key: 'Time Played', Value: '6d 1h 34m ' },
  { Key: 'Avg Survival Time', Value: '5m 44s' } ]
```

Comment: thanks but i already have all that info from the provided api its just the player level and current XP is not included